# why no search engine can search ~ sign?

Tags: c#, search-engine, yahoo

yesterday I was looking to know what is the meaning of `~` in C# and tried to search in Google,yahoo, and guess what? 
none of them index ~ 
I tried `"~", \\~ , '~'` and have no luck, it's surprising for me this symbol is not in the list .
I want to know why no search engine search this char? 
BTW if anyone know what is `~` in c# meaning and what is good for, made a big help to me

Comment: The web search you want is "download C# specification". Download the specification; no C# programmer should be without a copy. Don't rely on the Internet; read the spec.

Comment: C# specification is awesome, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/) to search code-related stuff. It handles symbols and indexes decent sites.

Try it out: http://symbolhound.com/?q=~+C%23

Comment: +1 Never knew about this.

Comment: +1 good site to search for the symbol meaning in each language

Answer (score 1):

`~` is the bitwise NOT [operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx).  It inverts every bit in an integer.

Ruthlessly stolen from MSDN:

```
~0x00000000 = 0xffffffff
~0x00000111 = 0xfffffeee
~0x000fffff = 0xfff00000
~0x00008888 = 0xffff7777
~0x22000022 = 0xddffffdd
```

Answer (score 0):

C# uses the `~` sign for two features. For the [bitwise not operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx) and for the declaration of a [destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: in my program it works as destructor, thanks for extra explanation.